# How can I get URI parameters - query string with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new at using javascript. For example, I have following url: `index.jsp?page=home&lang=eng` how can I extract parameters `home` and `eng` from the above url?

Question also answered: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: why would you need ajax for that..? Or did i get you wrong..!

Comment: I think he means JavaScript. Some people use that term interchangeably.....

Comment: I can get parameters by using request.getParameter() with java but I want to do that with jquery

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: You mean use ajax to get string values? not js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse an url's parameters:

```
var url = 'index.jsp?page=home&lang=eng';

var parse = function (url) {
    var getQuery = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1);
    var parts = getQuery.split('&');
    var key = null;
    var value = null;
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var keyValue = parts[i].split('=');
        key = keyValue[0];
        value = keyValue[1];
        result[key] = value;
    }
    return result;
};
```

The output of `parse(url)` would be an object that has the following structure:

```
{
    page: "home",
    lang: "eng"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to extract the exact URL param you want and will return "" empty string when can't find the paramter you search for:

```
function getUrlParam(param){
 var value = decodeURIComponent(
  (RegExp(param + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||["",""])[1]);
 return value;
} 

page_value = getUrlParam("page");    // home
lang_value = getUrlParam("lang");    // eng
```